# Expresso Store - Resend Order Email

Tags: expresso-store

I am currently using Expresso Store for non-members to purchase printable tickets for events. I don't want to require account creation for the checkout process but am concerned that a ticket purchaser will not receive an email with the order details.

I would like to be able to modify the order email and resend the confirmation mail. Is there anyway to do this with Expresso Store?

Answer (score 2):

In Store you can have multiple order emails and multiple order statuses. The easiest way to send a second email would be to assign a new template to an additional Order status. Then when you change the order status the second email will be sent.

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for, but it will work for now - Thanks for the information. I would still really like to see a simple "resend email" button next to the "Export to PDF" button. seems like a pretty simple addition.

Comment: Awww okay in that case I would send an email to support@exp-resso.com with the feature request so they can see about getting it added to a future release.

Answer (score 1):

To resend the email, simply change the order status. You can take advantage of the fact that by default the "order confirmation" email is tied to the "new" order status, and there is nothing to stop you changing a status to the same status.

So if you click "Edit Status" and then immediately hit "Submit" on the order details page, it will resend the order confirmation email for you.

Comment: This is good to know, I will use this but its not super obvious for novice users - still want mark this as complete as the ability to change the email address on the order is still something i would need.   Thanks!